# Supporting my Android 2.2 application  on Android 2.1 

Tags: android, xml, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I have developed an application in Android 2.2 and my clients want me to support it on 2.1
So I have some dependency for XML parsing
as I am using following code:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
//Set xmlns namespace otherwise xmlns will not be parsed
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new PersonalNamespaceContext());

//Parse XML string
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(CCRKEY1);          
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Now in 2.1 I cannot access `XPathFactory`, `XPath`, `XPathExpression`
So what could be the similar methods to replace these in 2.1??

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath support wasn't present in 2.1, so I think you'll have to do the parsing yourself via SAX or DOM, or use an external XPath lib, like [jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/) for instance. You could also use the [JAXP](http://jaxp.java.net/) library, which contains the official XPath implementation present in Java >5.

You can also keep both the methods, and use [`Build.VERSION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) to get the version under which the app is running.

Comment: Is there any other alternative? I learnt that by adding java 1.6 it can be done. How can I do it?

Comment: Android works on its own framework, which is a subset of Java 1.6, plus or minus some libraries. So, you won't be able to "add Java 1.6" to your app. All you can do is find another way of doing XPath.

Comment: jaxp-xalan-1.5 is not supporting in 2.1